# Mongodb pulling an object from array not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to delete an image object containing the image URL and filename from a post but my pull is not working as intended.

I'm using the image file name to find out which image object to delete but it seems like mongodb takes the filename and iterate through each of the characters in the filename and thats why it gives me this error.

I could simply find the object and edit the object directly using js syntax and do a `project.save()` .
However I dont think it is a very elegant solution. So if anyone has a solution, please help!

```
router.delete('/:project/:filename', verify, async (req, res) => {
  const filename = req.params.filename
  // const image = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: filename })
  // const image2 = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: path.basename(filename, path.extname(filename)) + '_compress' + path.extname(filename) })
  // if (!image) return res.status(404).send({ "error": "image not found" })

  const result = await Project.updateOne({
    _id: req.params.project,
    peopleInvolved: {
      $in: [req.user._id]
    }
  },
    {
      $pull: {
        image: { filename: filename }
      }

    })
  //TODO CHEKCK IF REMOVE BEFORE Delete
  console.log(await gfs.files.remove({ filename: filename }))
  console.log(await gfs.files.remove({ filename: path.basename(filename, path.extname(filename)) + '_compress' + path.extname(filename) }))

  res.send(result)
})
```

I get a Type Error:

```
/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js:24
    super(v);
    ^

TypeError: Iterator value e is not an entry object
    at new Map (<anonymous>)
    at new MongooseMap (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/map.js:24:5)
    at Map.cast (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/map.js:59:12)
    at Map.SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1135:12)
    at Map.SchemaType._castForQuery (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1567:15)
    at Map.SchemaType.castForQuery (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1557:15)
    at SchemaArray.castForQuery (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/array.js:545:20)
    at SchemaArray.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1534:20)
    at castUpdateVal (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/castUpdate.js:531:17)
    at walkUpdatePath (/Users/iceridge/Documents/GitHub/sutd-project-showcase/api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/castUpdate.js:343:24)
```

My post data looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "6210ac99555b141f8d0724d8",
"title": "post 5",
"peopleInvolved": [
{
"_id": "61e455a5ba6ec9dc13677d9b",
"name": "weihong",
"email": "weihong_qiu@mymail.sutd.edu.sg",
"studentId": 1005610,
"__v": 0
}
],
"desc": "another short desc",
"tag": [],
"courseNo": null,
"term": 1,
"startDate": "2021-02-01T16:00:00.000Z",
"endDate": "2021-02-04T16:00:00.000Z",
"telegram": "iceridge",
"linkIn": "https://www.linkedin.com",
"youtube": "https://www.youtube.com",
"otherLinks": {
"3drender": "www.example.com",
"arviewer": "www.ar.com"
},
"upvote": [],
"upvoteCount": 4,
"__v": 0,
"image": [
{
"filename": "eef709e2142c49861ab508a6ead32026.jpg",
"compressedFile": "eef709e2142c49861ab508a6ead32026_compress.jpg",
"id": "62189e793c7548ffc05ffbeb",
"originalname": "1 (19).jpg",
"uploadDate": "2022-02-25T09:16:42.781Z",
"contentType": "image/jpeg"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`peopleInvoked` is an object array. So, to match with the `req.user._id`, we need to use

```
{
    'peopleInvoice._id': {
        $in: [req.user._id]
    }
}
```

The `$pull` portion works just fine after changing the peopleInvoice `$in` part.

You can refer to the MongoDB Playground link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/emAhZMh7uML

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with mongoose schema definition. I changed from `image: {type: [Map]}` to `image: {type: []}` and it works perfectly